# Monks ki pool and temporary ability score increase

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, monk

At 4th level a monk gains access to a [ki pool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Ki-Pool-Su-) and its size is usually reflected by 1/2 level and wisdom modifier

> At 4th level, a monk gains a pool of ki points, supernatural energy he can use to accomplish amazing feats. The number of points in a monk's ki pool is equal to 1/2 his monk level + his Wisdom modifier.

When a spell like [owls wisdom](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/o/owl-s-wisdom) is cast on you, how exactly does this reflect on your ki pool?

> The transmuted creature becomes wiser. The spell grants a +4 enhancement bonus to Wisdom, adding the usual benefit to Wisdom-related skills. Clerics, druids, and rangers (and other Wisdom-based spellcasters) who receive owl's wisdom do not gain any additional bonus spells for the increased Wisdom, but the save DCs for their spells increase.

How I have played is that I track my uses of ki points. If I normally have 8 ki points and use them all, then have owls wisdom cast on me, I consider my pool to currently be 2 larger while the spell is active. If I use any of those points however, they still count towards the ones I have used, so after the spell runs out and is recast, I have still used those points.

Is this way correct or wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ability bonuses](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Ability-Score-Bonuses) can be defined by two categories, *temporary* and *permanent* bonuses. The difference between them is basically based on the duration of what caused this increase.

For the purpose of this answer, i will quote only the temporary bonus rules to wisdom, as those are relevant to *ki pool* class feature.

**Temporary Ability Bonus**

> **Wisdom**: Temporary increases to your Wisdom score give you a bonus on Wisdom-based **skill checks** and **Will** saving throws. This bonus also applies to any **spell DCs based on Wisdom**.

**Permanent Ability Bonus**

> Ability bonuses with a duration greater than 1 day actually increase the relevant ability score **after 24 hours**. **Modify all skills and statistics related to that ability**. This might cause you to gain skill points, hit points, and other bonuses. These bonuses should be noted separately in case they are removed.

So, after 24 hours, a [Headband of Inspired Wisdom +2](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/headband-of-inspired-wisdom) would increase your ki pool, AC bonus, will saving throw, skill checks related to wisdom, and anything else you got that is based on wisdom, by one.

But [Owl's Wisdom](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/o/owl-s-wisdom), lasting only 1 minute per caster level, does not last long enough to grant a permanent bonus.